# Using a SQL Server mdf file easy on any Windows without any authentication

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-2.0

I have a SQL Server `.MDF` database file that contains data and tables that I need to load into my project and add or update that data so when I attach the file and run my program on a second PC that has SQL Server already installed, I get error that database is not found!

**Note1:** database was created in SQL Server 2012 local host server and Windows authentication mode.

I am using this code for loading and using database :

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True");

    str = "CREATE DATABASE db1";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);

    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("First db is Created", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("DB is exist");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            //Open.the SqlConnection;
            con.Open();

            //The following code uses a SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE contents(id int IDENTITY(100, 1),Name char(50) NOT NULL,Lastname char(50) NOT NULL,Number char(50) ,Area nvarchar(50) ,Date nvarchar(50)NULL,Duration nvarchar(MAX),description nvarchar(MAX),gender nvarchar(50),number2 nvarchar(50),DT datetime NULL);", con))
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Tables created");
        }
    }
}
```

Load table

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from contents", c);
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(t);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
}
```

But it's not very unique and useful the db will be moved every day to another PC and it must load perfectly also I have some table in SQL file that are static and their is no need to code for them, I want to  just use them as resource. Also I heard about some method that embedded or local db can be used as db in app data folder and can be moved with app wisely so I need some help here. Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a `.mdf` file, you **must have** SQL Server to access it, and when using SQL Server, you **must use** either Windows or SQL Server authentication - you ***CANNOT*** access a `.mdf` file without any form of authentication ....

Comment: Why don't you just back up that database and restore it on the new PC. Or just connect directly to the database if both PC are in same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating a raw db everytime, you can use your mdf file as source,like below

```
Create database dbname 
On 
(   
Filename= 'path where you copied mdf file' 

)
For attach;
```

Comment: hmm  its good so we can use URL for a mdf file? interesting  actually i want to copy db in program folder i guess is debug  so use a default execute patch for Simplicity

Comment: the path can be shared path